# how to create placeholder while loading like facebook

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to create background loading lines like facebook did while loading the content using angular js.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could have a look at this blog post which describes in detail how the placeholders on Facebook work:

https://cloudcannon.com/blog/how-the-facebook-content-placeholder-works

Essentially, you put in some static html styled with css to look similar to the content that is coming.

```
<div class="placeholder">
  <!-- some boxes in light grey to look like content -->
</div>
```

When you are finished loading, you remove the placeholder:

```
$(".placeholder").remove();
```

Comment: currently provided url is 404 !. Any other alternate url?

Comment: @Raghu The link works for me, redirecting to https://cloudcannon.com/blog/how-the-facebook-content-placeholder-works. In any case, you can use the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/) in such situations.

Answer (score 61):

You can make it with some css background linear-gradient:

```css
@keyframes placeHolderShimmer{
    0%{
        background-position: -468px 0
    }
    100%{
        background-position: 468px 0
    }
}
.linear-background {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: placeHolderShimmer;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    background: #f6f7f8;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #eeeeee 8%, #dddddd 18%, #eeeeee 33%);
    background-size: 1000px 104px;
    height: 338px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="linear-background">
  
  
</div>
```

And paint with divs in white for a effect:

```css
@keyframes placeHolderShimmer{
    0%{
        background-position: -468px 0
    }
    100%{
        background-position: 468px 0
    }
}

.linear-background {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: placeHolderShimmer;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    background: #f6f7f8;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #eeeeee 8%, #dddddd 18%, #eeeeee 33%);
    background-size: 1000px 104px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inter-draw{
  background: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}
.inter-right--top{
  background: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 100px;
}
.inter-right--bottom{
  background: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 100px;
}
.inter-crop{
  background: #FFF;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="linear-background">
  <div class="inter-draw"></div>
  <div class="inter-crop"></div>
  <div class="inter-right--top"></div>
  <div class="inter-right--bottom"></div>
</div>
```

If you need to do multiple, this can be laborious, so this library automates: [placeload.js](https://github.com/victorvoid/placeload.js)

Comment: This would be impossible to use in real case scenario. But good design - it could be improved by using 100vw in background size, and then you could class individual DIV's without that one background wrapper

Answer (score 13):

If you guys ever need a npm package for placeholder loading animation, I made this: https://github.com/zalog/placeholder-loading

It's a library that can be configured as you need.
It's responsive, fast, simple, gpu optimized animation and css only.

Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Demo placeholder-loading</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/placeholder-loading/dist/css/placeholder-loading.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="ph-item">

      <div class="ph-col-2">
        <div class="ph-avatar"></div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class="ph-row">
          <div class="ph-col-4"></div>
          <div class="ph-col-8 empty"></div>
          <div class="ph-col-6"></div>
          <div class="ph-col-6 empty"></div>
          <div class="ph-col-2"></div>
          <div class="ph-col-10 empty"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ph-col-12">
        <div class="ph-picture"></div>
        <div class="ph-row">
          <div class="ph-col-10 big"></div>
          <div class="ph-col-2 empty big"></div>
          <div class="ph-col-4"></div>
          <div class="ph-col-8 empty"></div>
          <div class="ph-col-6"></div>
          <div class="ph-col-6 empty"></div>
          <div class="ph-col-12"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear Zalog, I try to use your library. But I don't know how to remove the grey background after the conten finished loading https://prnt.sc/vboln2 (screenshoot url)

Comment: @RezhaVelly after that ajax call you have to remove from dom entire div, and show/insert your new content/markup. I think this is a problem of javascript :) You can share your code in a jsbin, codepen, etc, and I can try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

**SHIMMER LOADING EFFECT**

Notice that the use of "vw" units eliminates the need for complicated masking. All elements are animated same speed.

Here's an updated look inspired by Google:
[image]

```css
.deferloading{
    cursor:default !important;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:1rem;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:0.8;
}
.deferloading.inline{
    display:inline;
}
.deferloading:before{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
    animation:2.2s ease forwards infinite placeHolderShimmer;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    background:linear-gradient(-61deg,#f2f2f2 40%,#E1E3E1 50%,#f2f2f2 60%);
    background-size:100vw 100%;
}
@keyframes placeHolderShimmer{
    0%{background-position:-50vw 0;}
    100%{background-position:50vw 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="deferloading">Hello buddy</div>
<br>
<div class="deferloading">Hello buddy extremely long....</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i light-skeleton
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/light-skeleton

```
const PreLoader = () => {
    let Hei = '100px';
    let MB = '15px';
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <TitleSkeleton 
          style={{ 
            margin: '5px', 
            marginBottom: MB
            }} 
          width={'90%'}
          height={Hei}
        />
        <TitleSkeleton 
          style={{ 
            margin: '5px', 
            marginBottom: MB
          }} 
          width={'90%'} 
          height={Hei}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
```